# Can AppHarbor deploy from a Tag rather than a Branch?

Tags: appharbor

I'd like to identify the code that AppHarbor checks-out and deploys via a Git tag.

This would tie in nicely with our versioning policy and give us more clarity around *what* is live exactly.

The fact that it would require an explicit update of the tag/version that I want to be deployed in AppHarbor is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

AppHarbor supports deploying from a tracking branch other than the default one, check "Deploy from non-default branch" in the [documentation](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments).

Comment: I've tried putting the tag in the 'tracking branch' but no luck. _#featurerequest_ :-)